# UWP Developing C++,C#,DirectX

Tags: c#, c++, uwp, directx-11, uwp-xaml

## Hello!

I Started building a game using UWP Platform and C#.
I am kind of new to the new platform.

My question is should I continue to build my game using C# and UWP only or should I start learning how to build games using C++ and UWP And DirectX 11?

## Notes:

*I know C# and XAML very good.
*I know a little bit of C++

*The game is 2D and does not require a lot of hard processing graphic

## The game will be specifically for Xbox One and Windows 10 PCs

## If I should learn DirectX and C++ using UWP what Resources/Sites do you recommend to start with?

Comment: As far as I know, this is off topic here. You *are* asking about, "software tools commonly used by programmers", but your question is *not* a ["a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Also, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam". This may be on topic over at http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't feel discouraged by the above. The question doesn't fit the rules of the site, but you're still among friends, even if some are really downvote happy.

Comment: I realize this question will likely be closed any minute. Please consider the points you lose when you downvote a question, whether it's worth downvoting a question already downvoted and whether you think it's worth having more people using Stack Overflow.

I think the question is a valid question about technology choices, with objective, helpful answers you can give. If you see specific issues with the question - consider updating the question or commenting on it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to know DirectX to build what you mentioned, although it never hurts to learn more to open up new possibilities. Look into DirectX when you find you can't achieve something with the technologies you use right now. You can build really cool games using just C# and XAML even though these are geared more towards UI development. If you only want to build games and don't care about building apps - you should look into some game building toolkits, such as Unity, since these will get you focused on building games. XAML might turn out to be a bit too limiting at some point. If you use DirectX - you'll spend more time building a game engine than building the actual game.

Comment: I think it depends a lot on what you plan to get out of the project. If you want to make a game and show your game design skills, then just go with something like Unity. If you want to learn how to create a game engine, then look at using C++ perhaps with the [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

Comment: Thank you for your help!